# I hit a curb and something got dislocated from under the vehicle. I wonder what is it

Tags: rubber

I was driving one day and accidentally hit a curb. When I check the damage, I see that this thing is now dangling from the bottom.
[image]

It's located almost directly beneath the engine to one side. The other side also has one. When I touch it, it feels like tyre rubber.

What is that? What does it do? Is it okay to drive? I want to see if I could repair it myself, but first I'd like to know what is it called in case I'd need to order replacement parts.

My car is a Mitsubishi Xpander.

Comment: Is the one on the other side also hanging off?

Comment: It looks to me like it is just the plastic lower engine cover that is used for sound deadening.  I presume the one on the other side isn’t a separate part, but just the other side of the cover.

Comment: Can you take another photo from the middle front of the car?

Comment: @HandyHowie - You're spot on. It's a lower cover which has come loose. You can see the mounting holes in it. Needs some new push pins and all should be right in the world.

Comment: I drive mine into the ground. If it's made out of plastic it's not important.

Comment: @Mazura Heh, you just wait...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seeing as @paulster2 agrees with me in the comments, I will make this into an answer -

It looks to me like it is just the plastic lower engine cover that is used for sound deadening. I presume the one on the other side isn’t a separate part, but just the other side of the cover.

As @paulster2 says - Needs some new push pins and all should be right in the world.

The pins are usually like a plastic rivet, but as a temporary fix, you may be able to use a cable tie (zip tie) through the holes to fasten it on.

Comment: "...as a temporary fix..."
*hello, apple? somebody spit coffee all over my laptop*

Comment: "There's nothing more permanent than temporary."

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Those zip ties may well outlive the cover itself!

Comment: Temporary = until the next compulsory vehicle check (cable-tie repairs are unlikely to pass).

Comment: 'Murican from a non-commie state here.  @OscarBravo what are those? :)

Comment: The lower plastic guard on the older Prius comes off so frequently, I wouldn't be surprised if the majority of them are zip tied. My wife took ours in once and when she started to explain the sip ties, the mechanic cut her off: "Let me guess, it's zip-tied. It's fine, this is the third zip-tied Prius today."

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Apparently, even in the Lone Star State, your vehicle has to come up to some [cock-a-mamy inspection standard](https://www.dps.texas.gov/rsd/vi/). They'll be banning smoking in bars next!

Comment: @OscarBravo oh, well, that's Texas. They're an exception to everything.  And they're nice enough to let us all be in the same customs union as them, so we don't mess with Texas :)

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say exactly from the picture, which was pretty dark, but it looks like it could be your anti-roll bar (also known as a sway bar or anti-sway bar). The anti-roll bar dampens side to side roll movement and helps keep your car stable in cornering or on uneven roads. It's safe to drive provided you drive very carefully and avoid and fast cornering or off-roading. If your front bar is broken you could have serious handling problems at highway speeds as well, it depends on the car. Basically as long as you drive like the stereotypical grandma (not mine, she got speeding tickets well into her 70s) you should be okay, but get it fixed!

Like so many other things in mechanics you can replace it at home provided you have the tools and space. You have to be able to get under the car and you may have to take off a lot of stuff to get to it. I know nothing about the Xpander, so I can't tell you how complex that job would be. If you do do it you should take the opportunity to inspect the area for other damage the curb strike may have caused, make sure nothing else is bent or loose. Check the bushings for wear or damage, and be prepared to replace them if needs be, if you're taking the time to do the work you don't want to put bad bushings back on!